# Force usage of custom attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

Scenario:
I have a base class "MyBase".
I have a custom attribute "MyAttrib"

With that I do this:

```
[MyAttrib(1234)]
class MyClass : MyBase()
{
 MyClass()
 {
 }
}
```

Question:
Can I in any way force classes inherting from MyBase to have the attribute MyAttrib?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, there is no way to have the compiler require an attribute in C#.  You do have some other options available to you.  You could write a unit test that reflects on all types in the assembly and checks for the attribute.  But unfortunately there is no way to have the compiler force the usage of an attribute.

Comment: See the answer below by @frederik-gheysels

Answer (score 3):

No longer relevant to the original poster I imagine, but here's something for anyone who's curious like I was if this was doable.

The following works, but sadly it's not a compile-time check and as such **I can't honestly recommend it used**. You're better off with interfaces, virtuals and abstracts for most things.

The required attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class RequiredRandomThingAttribute : Attribute { /* ... */ }
```

Parent class that requires it for derived classes:

```
public class ParentRequiringAttribute
{
    public ParentRequiringAttribute()
    {
        if (this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredRandomThingAttribute), false).Length == 0)
            throw new NotImplementedException(this.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

And to confirm it all works:

```
[RequiredRandomThing()]
public class CompleteSubclass : ParentRequiringAttribute { /* ... */ }

public class IncompleteSubclass : ParentRequiringAttribute { /* ... */ }

static public int Main(string[] args)
{
    var test1 = new CompleteSubclass();
    var test2 = new IncompleteSubclass(); // throws
}
```

It should be fairly easy to improve the validation, but my own investigation stopped here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use PostSharp for this.
Inherit your attribute class from the OnMethodInvocationAspect class (PostSharp), and override the CompileTimeValidate method.

A bit similar; albeit the other way around (I only wanted that a certain attribute could be applied to classes that implemented a specific interface):
http://fgheysels.blogspot.com/2008/08/locking-system-with-aspect-oriented.html

Answer (score 2):

What I did was have an abstract property or method in the `MyBase` class, so that inheriting classes are forced to override (and thus implement) this property/method.

Not as clean as an attribute, but better than checking at runtime in my opinion.

Comment: I think this would be even cleaner, if it fits the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that all classes of a base type or interface have an attribute, you can add a simple unit test that gets all of the derived classes and asserts they each have the attribute and add the results of the unit test into your further build process.