# How do I require a custom attribute be used on all class members if the class itself has a custom attribute?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the case of `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)`:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct UnionThingy
{
    [FieldOffset(0x00)]
    public short word;

    [FieldOffset(0x00)]
    public byte hiByte;

    [FieldOffset(0x01)]
    public byte lowByte;

    public bool additionalField;     // compile error!
}
```

Attempting to compile the above code results in the error [CS0625](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftd6k209%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

> 'UnionThingy.additionalField': instance field types marked with StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit) must have a FieldOffset attribute.

This seems an incredibly useful feature and I'm very curious how it is implemented.

I've read the MSDN tutorials on custom attributes, googled every related term I could think of, taken a look at the documentation for StructLayout and FieldOffset and even examined the metadata for those two attributes with "Go to definition..." in the VS code editor. I've been unable to find any clues on how the relationship between those two attributes is enforced.

If I want to do something similar:

```
[OptionalCustomAttribute]
public class DecoratedClass
{
    [DetailsRequiredByOptionalCustomAttribute(2)]    // compiler error if ommitted
    public int SomeProperty {get; set;}
}
```

How would I go about it?

Edit: The question [Force usage of custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974674), proposed as a duplicate, asks how to force classes that *inherit from a base class* to include an attribute, not how to enforce *members* of a decorated class to include a certain attribute. Also, the answer provided is "it can't be done", whereas in this case is clearly *has* been done by the authors of the .net libraries. The question is simply how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force usage of custom attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974674/force-usage-of-custom-attribute)

Comment: @Strikerz Thanks for the link, but that's a different situation entirely (see my edit).

Comment: Read the answers not the question

http://fgheysels.blogspot.ae/2008/08/locking-system-with-aspect-oriented.html

Comment: You definitely can do that too - build your own C# compiler that supports additional attributes... Probably way more work than you are willing to sign up for :)

Comment: @Strikerz That seems to show how to _prevent_ the use of an attribute based on inheritance, which is very different from what I'm looking to accomplish. I think I see why you believe that might be adaptable to this situation, but I'd much rather not rely on a third-party library to accomplish the task if there is a native solution.

Answer (score 2):

Some attributes contain information for the compiler. So naturally, there is explicit code in the compiler to interpret it and also error messages if this fails.

In our project, we have unit tests which load all types of our assemblies and check some attributes for consistency.

You can also make you application throw exceptions as early as possible (e.g. when starting up) in such cases. This is a simple solution if your application detects such errors anyway. It is important to throw early, otherwise you miss it until it went live...